# CSS min() function to SASS

Tags: css, sass, css-calc

I have CSS function like below:

```
width: min(calc(100vw - 51rem), calc(100vh - 2rem));
```

It's working fine when using a CSS file but not when used in SASS. How can I rewrite this function for SASS?

Comment: wv --> vw   .....

Comment: still not working after the edit?

Comment: no, look at Codepen: https://codepen.io/maxmets/pen/BajoGMM

Comment: you are using SASS so the min is trying to compile as SASS function

Comment: @TemaniAfif so how can I fix it?

Comment: @TemaniAfif it works when I go from SASS to CSS, but how can I write this function for SASS?

Comment: edit your question with these new information so we can reopen it and you will get an answer

Comment: try this `width: #{min(calc(100vw - 51rem), calc(100vh - 2rem))};`

Comment: "calc(100vw - 51rem)" is not a number for `min'
https://codepen.io/maxmets/pen/BajoGMM

Comment: @TemaniAfif could you please reopen this question because now nobody can answer?

Comment: you need to wait, 3 votes are needed to reopen the question

Comment: @TemaniAfif my question is still closed, is it possible to change it? It was my first attempt asking in SO and now I can not ask new question because my SO rate is down

Answer (score 38):

When using SASS, min() is a function within SASS itself therefore your statement is not making it to your CSS when processed.  There is a quick workaround since SASS is case sensitive and CSS is not.  Simply capitalize the "M" in Min().  The Min() statement will not be recognized as the internal SASS min() function but will work in CSS.

```
    width: Min(calc(100vw - 51rem), calc(100vh - 2rem));
```

Comment: Seems it doesn't works with linter base configuration

Comment: @ValEntin // stylelint-disable-next-line function-name-case

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap `min` in a `calc` and it works:

```
width: calc(min(calc(100vw - 51rem), calc(100vh - 2rem)));
```

In your case you can even simplify the code:

```
width: calc(min(100vw - 51rem, 100vh - 2rem));
```

Comment: Doesn't work with css variables

Comment: It does. To use SASS variables inside calc(), you need to wrap it in #{}, so it looks like this: calc(1px + #{$myVar})

Comment: Sorry, I meant it works, but the linter base configuration reject it some how, I guess it's too much confusion with min from CSS and SCSS, and I was talking about CSS variables var(--my-var) I'm injecting in my nodes, not SCSS variables which are compiled on build time. But Nice trick by the way.

Answer (score 7):

You can use these Sass functions to force the CSS functions.

```
@function css-function( $function, $values... ) {
    @return 
        $function
        + unquote( '(' )
        + $values
        + unquote( ')' )
    ;
}

@function css-min( $values... ) {
    @return css-function( min, $values );
}

@function css-max( $values... ) {
    @return css-function( max, $values );
}

@function css-clamp( $values... ) {
    @return css-function( clamp, $values );
}
```

You might still need to use #{ } interpolation when using Sass variables and CSS variables combined.

Usage:

```
$width-first: 40px;
$width-second: 30px;

.my-selector {
    width: css-min(#{$width-first}, #{$width-second});
}
```

Compiled:

```
.my-selector {
    width: min(40px, 30px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works well with css variables

Comment: You're welcome ☺️

Answer (score 0):

Replace node-sass with sass (dart-sass) in webpack bundler. And this problem will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

i (had to) use scssphp and i found i could just overwrite the `min` and `max` function, since i never used the sass functions anyways.

```scss
@function min($values...) { @return #{"min(" + $values + ")"}; }
@function max($values...) { @return #{"max(" + $values + ")"}; }
```